# getting a row value from an "id" column

Tags: php

in the following code, i would like to get the row result for column "id" as a result for $selectedmovieid. The 'commenid' is the primary key attribute. Sorry for not knowing how to use mysql_fetch_assoc properly.

```
<?php
require ("connect-comment.php");
$deleteid=$_GET['commentid'];
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM comment WHERE commentid='$deleteid'");
$selectedmovieid= mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM comment WHERE commentid='$deleteid'");
header("Location: reload.php?id=$selectedmovieid");
?>
```

EDIT 1: I will do up the security injection much later, just need to get the syntax right and get the right result. So this is what i have done so far:

```
<?php
require ("connect-comment.php");
$deleteid=$_GET['commentid'];
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM comment WHERE commentid='$deleteid'");
while ($selectedmovieid= mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
{echo $selectedmovieid['id'];};
$query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM comment WHERE commentid='$deleteid'");
header("Location: reload.php?id=$selectedmovieid");
?>
```

Now this doesn't make much sense to me cos i am not parsing the correct `$selectedmovieid` value into the `reload.php?id=`

Comment: If you type in `http://php.net/` and then the name of the function you need information about, you will be taken to the page in the PHP manual. The manual will almost always provide an example. http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Ouch. So much unsanitized user input...you never ever should insert something taken from the user (especially not GET parameters) into an SQL statement. And finding out how `mysql_fetch_assoc()` works should really be not too hard of a task. Just look it up in the documentation.

Comment: To elaborate on what Till means:  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: +1 @TillHelgeHelwig, especially in a `DELETE` statement - what if I request `http://yourdomain.tld/yourpage.php?commentid=1'+OR+'0'+=+'0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$deleteid=$_GET['commentid'];
// ...
header("Location: reload.php?id=$selectedmovieid");
```

to

```
$deleteid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['commentid']);
// ...
header("Location: reload.php?id={$selectedmovieid['id']}");
```

Also, as Pekka rightly suggests, try reading the [manual page for `mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) and [reading up on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

As a side note, you should **not** use relative paths for `Location:` header redirects. RFC's specify that this field should contain a **full URL** and, while many browsers will correctly interpret relative paths, this behaviour should not be relied upon. In other words, `Location: reload.php?id=...` should be `Location: http://mysite.tld/reload.php?id=`

**EDIT** Try this complete version of your sample code:

```
<?php

  require ("connect-comment.php");
  $deleteid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['commentid']);

  // Added LIMIT 1 to the query, because you are only using one result
  if (!$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `comment` WHERE `commentid` = '$deleteid' LIMIT 1")) {
    // Do NOT show the output of mysql_error() to the user in a production environment!
    exit("Something went wrong with query 1: ".mysql_error());
  } else if (mysql_num_rows($query1) < 1) {
    exit("No results from query 1");
  }
  $selectedmovieid = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
  $selectedmovieid = $selectedmovieid['id']; // $selectedmovieid now contains the id you want

  if (!$query2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `comment` WHERE `commentid` = '$deleteid'")) {
    // Do NOT show the output of mysql_error() to the user in a production environment!
    exit("Something went wrong with query 2: ".mysql_error());
  }

  // If we get this far, everything should be fine
  // You still need a full URL here though, not a relative path...
  header("Location: reload.php?id=$selectedmovieid");

?>
```